# ARM - UI for creating BlobStorage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I'm authoring a createUiDefinition.json file for an Azure application. I want to allow the user to create or select an existing Blob Storage account as part of deployment, using the [Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccountSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/microsoft-storage-storageaccountselector) control.

But when I'm running my UI definition through the Azure Portal, the StorageAccountSelector control doesn't seem able to create or find existing Blob Storage accounts, only general purpose Storage.

[image: screenshot 1]

There's also some weird behavior with the Standard/Premium buttons.

What's up with this? Are Blob Storage accounts not supported through this UI control? I'm sideloading the UI definition to the portal as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/test-createuidefinition), if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong - it's not supported yet...